# I cannot find bug in my code

Tags: php, mysql

This is code for a small login and sign up program. Each time user tries to log in this code checks if email and passwords are correct. The same query works if it is entered in mysql prompt.
I cannot figure out what is wrong in my code. Each time I enter valid email and password $result becomes FALSE.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "user";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection Error: ".mysqli_connect_error($conn));
    }
    $query = "select email, password from user_info where email = \'$_POST[login_email]\' or password = \'$_POST[login_password]\'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!$result)
        die("failure");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       $details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($details["email"] != $_POST["login_email"] && $details["password"] != $_POST["login_password"]) {
            die("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        echo "successful";
    }
    else {
        die("Don't have an account yet?. Please Sign Up to get started.");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use prepared statement..This is will cause sql injection

Comment: Do an echo of the parameters that you are getting from the Form. That is one thing, another is that that is a horrible practice what you are doing, you get hacked in 2 seconds, and sql injected. you are supposed to query by email AND password and not email OR password. So anyone knowing you email would get in.

Comment: Thanks both of you. That was a silly mistake @Arminius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lalithkumar is right. But as a temporary solution you can change the `$query` line to following

`$query = "select email, password from user_info where email = '".$_POST["login_email"]."' or password = '".$_POST["login_password"]."'";`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of array variables in a string is a tricky action:

```
$query = "select email, password from user_info where email = \'$_POST[login_email]\' or password = \'$_POST[login_password]\'";
```

Should read:

```
$query = "select email, password from user_info where email = ? or password=?"
$stmt=con.prepare($query)
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST[login_email]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST[password]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
```

This however would be that if the `login_email` is correct OR the password is correct, that you would get a result. So a 50% correct is good enough for this query checking credentials.

The next line is also interesting:

```
 if($details["email"] != $_POST["login_email"] && $details["password"] != $_POST["login_password"])
```

So both have to be incorrect to error out. Again just having a username or a random password (not even knowing which user it belongs to), is sufficient to login. A bit odd.